# What is the difference between <tiles:add> and <tiles:put> struts?

Tags: struts

What is the difference between `<tiles:add>` and `<tiles:put>` struts?

Answer (score 2):

`<tiles:add>` is equivalent to `<tiles:put>` but is used for list elements and can only be used inside the putList tag.

http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-tiles/tlddoc/tiles/add.html